# Адаптация сайта под смартфон, css

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка

Всем доброго времени суток. Решил адаптировать проект под мобильные устройства, а быть точнее пока только под свой смартфон. Сразу же возникла проблема, когда зашел на сайт, индексный файл выглядел сильно увеличенным(все элементы были большие), а когда перехожу на другую страницу по сайту, то там все поменьше. В чем может быть проблема? Фото предоставляю.

Индексный файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все остальные страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Суть вопроса не в самой адаптации, а в том, почему в индексе все большое, а в остальных нормальное.

Разметка индексного файла:

```
<?php 
include("blocks/db_con.php");
/*$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, meta_d, meta_k, ttext FROM settings WHERE page='about_us'", $db_connect);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);*/
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Головна - BusSmela</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobstyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax_image">
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top"></a>
        <?php
            $n = 1;
            include('blocks/header.php');
        ?>
        <table class="content">
            <tr>
                <?php
                    include('blocks/leftBlock.php');?>
                <td class="center">
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION["session_username"])) {
                    ?>
                    <h2>Вітаю, <span><u><?php echo $_SESSION['session_username'];?></u>! </span></h2>
                    <?php 
                        } else {?>
                            <h2>Вітаю, <span><u>гість</u>!</span></h2>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
            include('blocks/footer.php');
        ?>
        <a href="#" class="scrollup">Наверх</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Разметка другой страницы(о нас):

```
<?php 
include("blocks/db_con.php");
/*$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, meta_d, meta_k, ttext FROM settings WHERE page='about_us'", $db_connect);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);*/
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Про нас - BusSmela</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobstyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax_image">
        <?php
            $n = 4;
            include('blocks/header.php');
        ?>
        <table class="content">
            <tr>
                <?php
                    include('blocks/leftBlock.php');?>
                <td class="center">
                    <div class="aboutBlocks"><h2>Наша мета</h2>
                    BusSmela пропонує своїм користувачам простий і зручний сервіс для пошуку маршрутів. Наші користувачі можуть отримати всі доступні варіанти поїздок.</div>
                    <div class="aboutBlocks"><h2>Наш сервіс</h2>
                    BusSmela не є перевізником, але ми докладаємо всіх зусиль, щоб користувачі могли швидко знайти свій маршрут. Ми намагаємося взаємодіяти з перевізниками з питань пунктуальності.</div>
                    <div class="aboutBlocks"><h2>Наші ціни</h2>
                    Ціни на квитки встановлені самими перевізниками.</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
            include('blocks/footer.php');
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Стили для смартфона:

```
@media (max-width: 1080px) {
  * {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
  }

  .timeflight {
    float: right;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }

  ul:after {
    float: left;
  }

  ul li .sss:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    float: right;
  }

  .sss:focus ~ ul li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
  }

  .outdb {
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(27,78,137, 0.5);
    color: white;
  }

  .spek {
    width: 60%;
  }

  .img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .img {
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }

  .search {
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  a:hover,
  a:link,
  a:active,
  a:visited {
    color: #91C4FF;
    font-size: 65%;
  }

  .ic {
    width: 3%;
  }

  .icons {
    width: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 1%;
  }

  .back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 40%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    display: none;
  }

  .back-to-top:hover,
  .back-to-top:focus {
    filter: brightness(1.5);
    outline: none;
  }

  .back-to-top::before,
  .back-to-top::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 35px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .aboutBlocks {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: center;
    font-size: 100%;
  }

  .back-to-top::before {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  }

  .back-to-top::after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -65%) rotate(45deg);
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  }

  body,html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

  .parallax_image {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .parallax_image:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url(images/bgimage.JPG);
  }

  .image {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
  }

  .foot {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .foot2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .input {
    width: 240px;
    height: 42px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #021EB2;
    background: #CAFFFF;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s linear;
  }
  .input:focus {
    width: 300px;
    background: #97E6FD;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
  }

  .logo {
    height: 140px;
  }

  .btn {
    display: inline;
  }
  .inputbtn {
    --width: 270px;
      --height: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
      line-height: var(--height);
      color: #021EB2;
      padding: 0; 
      border: none; 
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 67%;
      letter-spacing: 8px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
  }

  .button {
      --width: 270px;
      --height: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #021EB2;
      padding: 0; 
      border: none; 
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 67%;
      letter-spacing: 8px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #02D0F3;
  }

  .button2 {
      --width: 270px;
      --height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
      line-height: var(--height);
      color: yellow;
      padding: 0; 
      border: none; 
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 67%;
      letter-spacing: 8px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
      background: #02D0F3;
  }

  .headerMain {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28%;
    background-color: #02D0F3;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer {
    background-color: #00063B;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    font-size: 50px;
  }

  .content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .left {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: rgba(27,78,137, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }

  .center {
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: rgba(27,78,137, 0.4);
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
}
```

Comment: достали вы со своими скриншотами ..код где ?ссылка на сайт

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо за ответ. Изменил. Дело в том, что стили применяются ко всем страницам и на ноутбуке отображает все гуд. А вот именно на смартфоне и именно индексный файл вот такой. Хотя все такое же как и на остальных страницах

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` вот это добавьте в head

Comment: @MaximLensky Я так понимаю в каждый файл разметки? После этого все страницы становятся похожими на индексный файл. Если без этого мета тега верстать, будет ли считаться это версткой под смартфон? Мало ли

Comment: нет ... вы используете php там делов то добавить это ...

Comment: @MaximLensky не рычи))

Comment: @MaximLensky Та мне то не сложно, просто уточняю

Comment: @ВладиславВешневский Да, так и нужно. Крупным оно становится как раз из-за адаптации. Вы же не хотите, чтобы конечный пользователь пытался нажать на кнопочку в 3 пикселя, и после кучи попыток сдался и пошёл на сайт конкурентов? Можно и без него на самом деле обойтись, но это уже будут костыли (да и зачем оно вообще надо костылить?).